# creating a function that loops if you do not enter the correct variables

Tags: python, loops

I am looking to create a function that loops again if you do not enter the right string.

The issue with this code is that I seem to have it loop endlessly

```
def askString(question):
    while True:
        try:
            response = str(input(question))
            if response != "a" or response != "b" or response != "c":
                 print("please enter a/b/c")
                 continue
            break
    return response

trial = askString("please enter a/b/c :")
```

I referenced this code for my looping. At the present, it works well for integers but not very well for string.

```
def askInt(question): 
     while True:       
         try:          
             response = int(input(question)) 
             if response <= 0: 
                print("please enter positive value greater than zero") 
                   continue  
             break 
         except ValueError: 
             print("integers only please")
     return response
```

any suggestions as to what is causing the endless loops for strings but not for the integer code?

Thank You

Comment: you should use `else: break`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your if statement:

```
if response != "a" or response != "b" or response != "c":
```

Since the response can't be "a", "b" and "c" simultaniously, the condition is always true, therefore the loop never breaks.
Use

```
if (response != "a" and response != "b" and response != "c"):
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems:

1. input() already returns a str, no need to call str again
2. No need to call print("please enter a/b/c"), if you pass question to input, it will print it to the screen, so calling print again will just double it.
3. As a good practice, you could put the letters in a list, and check if the response in in that list, such that you have shorter code.

```py
def askString(question):
    while True:
            response = input(question)
            if response  in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
                 break

    return response

trial = askString("please enter a/b/c :")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from your `or` statements. You should use `and` instead. Otherwise, your input will necessary be different from "a" or "b" or "c", and the loop will never break.

And the `try:` part is not necessary since you do not use `int()`function

```
def askString(question):
    while True:
        response = str(input(question))
        if response != "a" and response != "b" and response != "c":
            continue
        break
    return response

trial = askString("please enter a/b/c :")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this:

for a postive integer,

```
def askInt():

  response = int(input('Enter a  number'))
  while response < 0:
    response = int(input('Enter a  positive number'))
  print(response)
```

```py
def askStr():

  response = (input('Enter string a,b or c'))
  while response != 'a' and response != 'b' and response != 'c':
    response = (input('Enter correct reponse'))
  print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work a bit better:

```
def askString(question):
    valid_answers = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    while True:
        response = str(input(question)).strip()
        if response in valid_answers : break

        print("please enter a/b/c")

    return response
```